# import python module fails

Tags: python, jenkins

I am unable to import this module, not sure what the issue is, when I enter: help('modules'), it is listed there.  When I try to import other modules, I do not get this error.

```
~$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jenkinsapi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jenkinsapi/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    __version__ = pkg_resources.working_set.by_key['jenkinsapi'].version
KeyError: 'jenkinsapi'
```

Comment: how did you install it?

Comment: What is your operating system, distribution, CPU, system, etc.?

Comment: pip install jenkinsapi, CentOS 6.5 vm (ESXi 5.5 vmware), Kernel 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64

Comment: Jenkinsapi author here. Can you confirm that your pip and setuptools are both up to date?

Comment: pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)
python-setuptools-0.6.10-3.el6.noarc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Centos 6.4, Python 2.6.6, jenkinsapi 0.2.25 via pip and was getting the same error.

What I found out is that jenkinsapi is adhering to a (deferred) python standard [pep-396](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/), it seems like maybe the addition was pretty recent according to [this post](http://salimfadhley.wordpress.com/2014/07/29/low-hassle-pep-396/#comments) from one of the project's contributors.

As your console output shows jenkinsapi's init is trying to set its __version__ from what pkg_resources already knows.  I was able to confirm that in my case pkg_resources.working_set was not loading jenkinsapi despite the sys.path correctly including the site-packages directory where it lived.  However, like you, it was finding other modules I had just installed.  This really seemed like a confused python to me so
before digging in too deep I did a "pip uninstall jenkinsapi" and on a hunch I tried the other installation method listed in the documentation; "easy_install jenkinsapi".
That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Submitted this bug here - https://github.com/salimfadhley/jenkinsapi/issues/333

Installing 0.2.22 via pip works as expected so another solution is to use the older version.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing a similar problem and have a not very nice workaround for now using unittest.

```
import unittest
test_loader = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover(start_dir= '.', pattern='test_controller.py')
test_runner = unittest.runner.TextTestRunner()
result = test_runner.run(test_loader).wasSuccessful()
```

Not nice but it means I can call a stub which in turn calls the main code which is pulled in from Git.
The stub contains a standard unittest.testCase derived class.